# In Visual Studio 2012 in the Call Stack window, what does the light green curved arrow indicate?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, callstack

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to debug a program.

In the Call Stack window, what does the light green curved arrow indicate?

[image: Light Green Curved Arrow in Call Stack]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx

> ## How to: Use the Call Stack Window
>
> A yellow arrow identifies the stack frame where the execution pointer is currently located. By default, this is the frame whose information appears in the source, Disassembly, Locals, Watch, and Autos windows. If you want to change the context to another frame on the stack, you can do that in the Call Stack window.
>
> To switch to another stack frame
> 1 In the Call Stack window, right-click the frame whose code and data that you want to view.
> 2 Select Switch to Frame.
> A green arrow with a curly tail appears next to the frame you selected. The execution pointer remains in the original frame, which is still marked with the yellow arrow. If you select Step or Continue from the Debug menu, execution will continue in the original frame, not the frame you selected.

Also, variables you mouse over and in the watch window will show the values as seen by the currently selected frame.  If there's a `i` variable in the "real" frame and a different `i` variable in the "selected" frame, when you mouse over a variable with the name `i` it will show the value of the `i` variable in the "selected" frame.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize this.  I thought the Visual Studio was trying to specifically point something out to me with the green arrow.